# Format USB disk with DISKPART

Tags: windows, usb, partitioning

I'm trying to format a USB disk, however, it won't format as expected:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          119 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          465 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 2    Online         7620 MB  7619 MB

DISKPART> select Disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

There are no partitions on this disk to show.

DISKPART> detail disk

Generic Flash Disk USB Device
Disk ID: 38B13909
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 2     E                       Removable       0 B  Unusable

DISKPART> select volume 2

Volume 2 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> FORMAT RECOMMENDED OVERRIDE

    0 percent completed

Virtual Disk Service error:
The cluster size is too big.


DISKPART> FORMAT FS=FAT32 LABEL="USB"

    0 percent completed

DiskPart has encountered an error: The parameter is incorrect.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART>
```

When using Linux, however, it can be formatted properly using *gparted* tool. Why DISKPART is unable to format the disk, what could be wrong here?

Comment: In diskpart, use `clean` and `create partition primary` and `active` to create a new partition.

Comment: Your first clue was when it said "There are no partitions to show." In every OS that I am familiar with, you cannot format a disk that hasn't been partitioned first. Run diskpart and  enter "help" it will list the internal commands it supports. Entering "HELP <command>" will break it down into further detail about each command.

Answer (score 1):

You used the RECOMMENDED parameters and so let DiskPart choose the file-system format
that it decides is the best.

Evidently, the chosen format, whatever it was, was unsuitable for the drive in question.

I suggest dictating the format to use by a command such as:

```
format fs=ntfs label="Main Volume" quick
```

If the drive in question is not very large, `fat32` might be a better choice than
`ntfs`.

Reference : [DISKPART FORMAT](https://ss64.com/nt/diskpart-format.html).